# Conjecture about fixed prime divisors of polynomials with integer coefficients

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, reference-request, prime-numbers, conjectures

While experimenting with random polynomials I've found this conjecture:

> A polynomial $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$ of degree $n$ with co-prime coefficients
> have no fixed prime divisor $p> n$.

A fixed prime divisor is a prime $p$ such that $p|f(m)$ for all $m\in\mathbb Z$.

Is this known? Proved? Or are there counterexamples?

Comment: Where did you find this conjecture?

Comment: @SmileyCraft: as I wrote, I've done some experimenting. With my own software Bigz.

Comment: do you mean pairwise co-prime?  If you mean that there should be no prime which divides all the coefficients then it seems to be false.  For instance, take $f(x)=x(x+1)(x+2)=x^3+3x^2+2x$.  Clearly $2\,|\,f(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Right...but you required that $p<n$.  Here $p=2$, $n=3$.

Comment: @lulu: I have changed it. A kind of typo, I hope.

Comment: @lulu And obviously also $3|f(n)$ if that is required.

Comment: Ok, but the $p>n$ case is trivial.  No polynomial of degree $n<p$ can vanish for all the residues $\pmod p$ and your polynomial can't reduce to $0\pmod p$ since that would imply that every coefficient was divisible by $p$.

Comment: @MarkBennet  True! But apparently this is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: And little Fermat implies that $p | x^p-x$ for all primes $p$

Comment: @lulu: It wasn't trivial for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $p$ does not divide each of the coefficients of $f(x)$, $f(x)$ reduces to a non-trivial polynomial $\overline f(x)$ of degree $≤n$ $\pmod p$.  But if $p>n$ then $\overline f(x)$ can have at most $n$ roots $\pmod p$, hence it is non-zero on at least one residue $a \pmod p$. But then $f(a)\not \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and we are done.